# How could I call an abstract class method who is common between subclasses without instanciating any subclass

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract-class

I have a code like this :

```
interface Contract {
  createSomething(); //not common
  updateSomething(); //not common
  getSomething(); //method who is supposed to be common between all strategies
}
```

```
interface Strategy {
  createSomething();
  updateSomething();
  getSomething();
}
```

```
Abstract class AbstractStrategy implements Strategy {

  @Override
  getSomething() {
    // the common code
  }
}
```

```
class strategyA extends AbstractStrategy {

  @Override
  createSomething() {...}

  @Override
  updateSomething() {...}
}
```

```
class ContractImpl implements Contract {

  @Override
  createSomething() {
    //get the good strategy 
    //call the strategy.createSomething();
  }

  @Override
  updateSomething() {
    //get the good strategy 
    //call the strategy.updateSomething();
  }

  @Override
  getSomething() {
     **Here is the question**
  }
}
```

Question:

> - How could I rewrite this code so I could call the getSomething() method without having to instanciate a random subclass just to call it with the super keyword ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't because that's the point of an abstract class. Or you're looking for a static method, but that's different.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Rather, you could extract the code into a static method and subsequently call it from `getSomething()`. This would allow you to call it statically when you need to, *and* from an instance when needed as well.
In other words, your `AbstractStrategy` class should look like:

```
Abstract class AbstractStrategy implements Strategy {
    public static void sharedCode(parameters needed) {
        // the common code
    }


    @Override
    (signature) getSomething() {
        sharedCode(this.parametersNeeded);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't use a static method because the getSomething method uses objects who are not static

Comment: If you have the objects that the method needs (which you should, if you don't have a child object but still want the method called), you can add parameters to the static method and pass them in in both places.

Comment: If I understand, the method sharedCode has the content of the getSomething method ? Problem is the common code in sharedCode method makes database access, so it uses class variable that I inject in my Abstract class.

Comment: Then you would need to provide that same variable to the static method. The problem seems to be that if you do have an instance, then there is no DB connection. You therefore cannot accomplish what you want to do. You could, however, pass the variable into the static method and create the connection there. Then you would be able to do what you're attempting to do both statically and in instances. If that's not an option, you'll likely have to duplicate code, one in a static method and one in an instance. Static methods are the only methods that can run without an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't. An abstract class can't be instantiated, so you can't call an instance method without having an object of a concrete implementation (in your case any concrete subclass of `AbstractStrategy`).

One option that you have is to create an anonymous class so that you can call the method without instantiating any of your subclasses of `AbstractStrategy`:

```java
AbstractStrategy strategy = new AbstractStrategy() {
  @Override
  createSomething() {...}

  @Override
  updateSomething() {...}
}
strategy.getSomething();
```

But this feels hacky.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know it's not possible to instanciate an abstract class. The question is how can I build my code so I can handle createSomething() and updateSomething in subclasses, and handle getSomething() in only one place for every strategies

Comment: But that is exactly what your `AbstractStrategy` provides, a single place where `getSomething()` is implemented. What it can't provide you is to be able to call such a method without having an object of `AbstractStrategy` type. In order to have such an object, you must have an object of a concrete implementation of it, there is no way around that (unless you want to use static methods, but it seems to me that you don't). You could use an anonymous class if you don't want to use one of your sub-classes in that case.

Comment: If your fear is that a subclass of `AbstractStrategy` might have overridden its `getSomething()` implementation, then mark it as final in `AbstractStrategy`: `final void getSomething() { // the common code }`.